# Symfony 2 UniqueEntity repositoryMethod fails on Update Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, unique-constraint

I'm working on some simple script, but can't wrap my head around this problem.
So here it is.

```
/**
 * Booking
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tons\BookingBundle\Entity\BookingRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"room", "since", "till"}, repositoryMethod="getInterferingRoomBookings")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isSinceLessThanTill"}, groups={"search","default"})
 */
class Booking
```

and repository Method

```
/**
     * Get room state for a certain time period
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInterferingRoomBookings(array $criteria)
    {
        /** @var $room Room */
        $room = $criteria['room'];
        $builder = $this->getQueryForRoomsBooked($criteria);
        $builder->andWhere("ira.room = :room")->setParameter("room", $room);
        return $builder->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

The problem is that this works on create methods like it should,
but when updating existing entity - it violates this constrain.

I tried to add Id constrain, but when creating entities, id is null, so repository Method don't even starts.
Also i tried to remove Entity and then recreate it. like

```
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
//-----------
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

but this also does not work.

Create Action

```
 /**
     * Creates a new Booking entity.
     *
     * @Route("/create", name="booking_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("TonsBookingBundle:Booking:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Booking();
        $form = $this->createForm(new BookingType(), $entity);
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $room = $entity->getRoom();
            if($room->getLocked() && $room->getLockedBy()->getId() === $this->getUser()->getId())
            {
                $entity->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
                $entity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
                $entity->setManager($this->getUser());

                $em->persist($entity);
                $room->setLocked(false);
                $room->setLockedBy(null);
                $room->setLockedAt(null);
                $em->persist($room);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('booking_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
            }
            else
            {
                $form->addError(new FormError("Номер в текущий момент не заблокирован или заблокирован другим менеджером"));
                return array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                );
            }
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Update Action

```
 /**
     * Edits an existing Booking entity.
     *
     * @Route("/edit/{id}/save", name="booking_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("TonsBookingBundle:Booking:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        /** @var $em EntityManager */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('TonsBookingBundle:Booking')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Booking entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new BookingType(), $entity);
        $editForm->bind($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('booking_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Please post the Controller createAction.

Comment: @Lighthart added methods, but they are standart from doctrine:generate:crud

Comment: `$room->setLockedAt(null);` does not want to work for me, no idea why. My field is DateTime but nullable, entering `' '` or `null` give me an error:    Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\User::setLockedAt() must be an instance of DateTime, null given,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this! 
I changed annotation to this

```
/**
 * Booking
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tons\BookingBundle\Entity\BookingRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"id","room", "since", "till"}, repositoryMethod="getInterferingRoomBookings")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"room", "since", "till"}, repositoryMethod="getInterferingRoomBookings",groups={"create"})
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isSinceLessThanTill"}, groups={"search","default"})
 */
class Booking
```

Copy BookingType to BookingTypeCreate And added

```
 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tons\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking',
            'validation_groups' => array('create'),
        ));
    }
```

To form defaults. So now parameters are different when passing entity to validation method.
I think it's still a workaround method.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You're not getting the form data into the entity, so you are working with a new entity that does not know its room has been set in the form.

Long answer:  Getting the form data and putting it into the entity allows you to manipulate the data before update.  See modified controller below.  Key line is

`$entity = form->getData();` Which then allows you to `$room=$entity->getRoom();`

```
/**
 * Creates a new Booking entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="booking_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("TonsBookingBundle:Booking:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Booking();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookingType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);
$entity = $form->getData();  // Lighthart's addition
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $room = $entity->getRoom();
        if($room->getLocked() && $room->getLockedBy()->getId() === $this->getUser()->getId())
        {
            $entity->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $entity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $entity->setManager($this->getUser());

            $em->persist($entity);
            $room->setLocked(false);
            $room->setLockedBy(null);
            $room->setLockedAt(null);
            $em->persist($room);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('booking_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
        else
        {
            $form->addError(new FormError("Номер в текущий момент не заблокирован или заблокирован другим менеджером"));
            return array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            );
        }
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunatelly it's not the case. You talking about create method, but that one is only triggered, when new entity is created, edit method calls updateAction(). Anyway i tried that, and it didn't work. I suppose that bind($request) does the job on populating form data into entity. $room actually getting the right value. In the update method you get the entity from db, and then populate it with form data, and when validate is triggered. uniqueEntity fails because   method returning the same entity, which already in the database.

Comment: The symfony default is new calls create and edit calls update.  In any event, you might need the same form->getData().

Comment: yeah, but $form->getData() already called inside $form->bind(request); so you don't need another getData. Entity is already mapped properly from form. Validation actually fails because the entity could not be saved, because the entity which i want to persist already in the database. You know, because it's the same entity.

Comment: I can't find any getData() call assigned to underlying entity in form.php, so I'm not sure your claim about data being written to the entity can be supported (in fact I read the code with quite a different interpretation).  At this point I cannot tell if you are unhappy with update or create.  Please clarify.  My next guess is that your formtype is a bit goofy, but can't really know unless that's default symfony code as well.

Comment: FormTypes are default, create works fine, but update claims that entity violate constraint in uniqueEntity function - getInterferingRoomBookings(array $criteria). Which return an array of bookings for this room and where booking's period is crossing. So it can't update entry, because of constraint violation, even it's the same entity that violates it and the one you want to update.

Comment: Wow, I very badly misunderstood the problem.  Why don't you just delete the room from the array that gets returned in your validation call?

Comment: I need that constraint to protect against crossing bookings. If i just delete the booking from array, than having these constraints is pointless. I need to find out, is the violating entity and edited entity the same somehow,  but i really can't figure it out only by validating criteria. if i change criteria to contain an id to the entity, then validation does not trigger in create method, so i will got a bigger problem.

Comment: i think i figured it out somehow.

Comment: Great.  I hope I only slowed you modestly.

Answer (score -1):

Pass an additional identifier (maybe a `token`) to the unique check field (for example `loginName`) (`fields={"token", "loginName"}`), to the repositoryMethod. The `id` itself is not working, it is null on object creation and the repositoryMethod is not executed. I create the `token` in the constructor Method. The token is needed to identify the entity on creation or update action.

```
/**
  * @ORM\Table(name="anbieterregistrierung")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AnbieterRegistrierungRepository")
  * @UniqueEntity(
  *      fields={"token", "loginName"},
  *      repositoryMethod="findUniqueEntity"
  * )
  */
```

then in repository class you edit the WHERE DQL:

```
public function findUniqueEntity(array $parameter)
    {
        $loginName = $parameter['loginName'];
        $token = $parameter['token'];
.
.
.
. . . WHERE anbieterregistrierung.loginName = :loginName AND anbieterregistrierung.token <> :token
.
.
.
}
```