# Symfony 4 Validation on whole Entity

Tags: php, symfony, validation, doctrine, symfony4

So, I need a validation for a reservation for a sports club.
A reservation has a start and an end datetime and you can reservate for 1 or more tables.

So the Entity looks like

```php
class Reservation
{
    use TimestampAble;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="reservations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Table", inversedBy="reservations")
     */
    private $tables;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $end;

    ...
}
```

(Don't worry about the entity "Table" - the db table for it is named "snooker_table" ;))

Now I need to validate, that in the requested time range with the requested tables no other reservation already exist. 
And this gives me headaches...

I know I can make it "manually" in the Controller Actions create / update. But I'm also using Symfonys Easy-Admin, so I need to put the code there as well.
I thought about putting the validation as an annotation directly into the entity. But I don't know where... If I put it on "$tables" I just get an ArrayCollection without the needed start and end datetimes. And it's also not an unique entity (as I need to go on a range of datetimes and so on).

So: any ideas how to achieve this in the entity directly? or at least in the form type (and for easy admin i care later)?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating a [custom constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)?

Comment: Well the constraint itself isn't that much the problem. But WHERE to put it...

Comment: As in the code itself? Or in the `Reservation` entity? The last section dives into class validation instead of property validation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to do it in this way: [Symfony 2 UniqueEntity repositoryMethod fails on Update Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148678/symfony-2-uniqueentity-repositorymethod-fails-on-update-entity)

Creating a repository method (not a constraint) for validation and use it for the UniqueEntity constraint on the whole entity itself. Feels a little bit dirty but ok...
Hope this works in easy admin as well.

Comment: You have to create a constraint too. In you're custom constraint, you could use the repository to find if you're constraint fail or not

Comment: The UniqueEntity is the constraint.